# Single $\Delta$-complex structure on $S^3$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Is it possible to identify pairs of faces of $\Delta^3$ to produce a $\Delta$-complex structure on $S^3$ having a single simplex?

I'm thinking to identify left with right and behind with bottom. But I cannot visualize what I can obtain and how can I make sure I get $S^3$?

Comment: Well, you can take $\Delta^3$ and collapse the boundary to a point. But that's not a $\Delta$-complex.

Comment: This is an exercise in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, chapter 2.1, so it should be possible. I think you have to identify the faces in pairs, as you suggested.

Comment: Hm, you can visualize a tetrahedron with one pair of faces identified as the suspension of $D^2$. Think of two solid cones attached at their bottoms. If you now identify the other faces, you identify $(x,t)$ with $(x,-t)$ for $x\in S^1$ and $t\in I$. YOu can also think of $D^3$ with each point on the boundary identified with its reflection at the $x-y-$plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify $[012] \sim [013]$ and $[123]\sim[023]$. The first identification $[013] \sim [012]$ happens by stretching one face around to meet the other. Then we are left with a double-cone, and completing the next identification $[123] \sim [023]$ is the same identifying the faces of the cone as mirror images, or via reflection. (I found this easiest to visualize by drawing two pictures from the perspective of each tip of the cone.)

We now just need to see that $S^3$ is homotopic to $D^3/\sim$ with $x \sim r(x)$ for $x \in \partial D^3$, and $r$ being reflection through some plane passing through an equator.

To see it, instead imagine the 3-cell of $D^3$ as being the space outside of the boundary sphere. Then, to identify the boundary sphere via the reflection map is just to crush it to a disc. We may now contract this disc to a point, and what we have is $S^3$ since we have started with $D^3$ and glued precisely all of the boundary points together, i.e. $D^3/\partial D^3 \cong S^3$.

We can be a little more rigorous and see that the space is even homeomorphic to $S^3$. Consider $D^3$ inside the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is homeomorphic to $S^3$. Then we embed $D^3 \to \widehat{\mathbb{R}^3}$ via $x \mapsto \dfrac{x}{||x||^2}$, mapping $0$ to the point at infinity. What we have then is $S^3$ with an open ball we need to remove. Consider a Euclidean neighborhood around this ball, then removing it and crushing its boundary to a disc, we still have a Euclidean neighborhood. And this is our space, $S^3$.

As a check, I have computed the homology in the three cases, and the only time we get the correct homology for $S^3$ is with the above identification.

[Edit: The previous paragraph is based on a faulty computation of one of the other cases, which has since been corrected. As such, case (2) below *could* also yield $S^3$, but the writer is unsure of whether it does or not.]

(1) If you identify $[012]\sim[013]$ and $[123]\sim[023]$ you get
$$H_n(X) = \begin{cases}\mathbb{Z}&\text{ if } n=3\\0&\text{ if } n=2\\0&\text{ if } n=1\\\mathbb{Z}&\text{ if } n = 0.\end{cases}$$

(2) If you identify $[012]\sim[123]$ and $[013]\sim [023]$ you get
$$H_n(X) = \begin{cases}\mathbb{Z}&\text{ if } n=3\\ 0&\text{ if } n=2\\ 0 &\text{ if } n =1\\ \mathbb{Z} & \text{ if } n = 0.\end{cases}$$

(3) If you identify $[012]\sim [023]$ and $[013]\sim[123]$ you get
$$H_n(X) = \begin{cases}0&\text{ if } n=3\\ \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} &\text{ if } n = 2\\ 0&\text{ if } n=1\\ \mathbb{Z} & \text{ if } n=0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: It seems to me that $H_2(X)$ in Case (2) is $\mathbb Z^2$, not $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @fish I tried to count just now and I think the identifications in case 2 give a chain complex with dimension vector $(1,2,1,1)$. Given that all the edges are the same I think the differential in degree 2 would be nonzero. (It has been quite a while since I computed with delta complexes though)

Comment: I believe [03] does not get identified to any other edge. The full calculation I did (using [01] to denote the edge-that-isn't-[03]) was $\partial([012]) = [12] - [02] + [01] = [01]$ and $\partial([013]) = [13] - [03] + [01] = 2[01] - [03]$. Together it seems that the kernel of $\partial_2$ is all of $C_2$.

Comment: @fish I think you're right, I missed $[03]$

Comment: @fish Doesn't your calculation show the kernel of $\partial_2$ is 0 though? And then the homology is that of a sphere?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. Unfortunately I don't think I have the geometric intuition to tell whether the delta complex ends up actually being the sphere...